# Azure AD B2C - Custom Client library instead of MSAL/ADAL?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, adal, azure-ad-msal

Lets say, an organization uses Azure AD B2C for their IAM needs and their APIs are protected by AD B2C. Any client application that needs to obtain tokens from Azure AD B2C can utilize the client library [MSAL] to interact with IAM.

This mandates the organisation to suggest using MSAL to their partner or independent client App developers. In this case if the organisation do not want their developers/partners to know that they are using azure AD B2C, what will be the right approach? Should they build their own custom client libraries? Or are there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this case if the organisation do not want their developers/partners to know that they are using azure AD B2C

I don't think you can fully hide that.  Even w/ [custom domains](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334317-customer-owned-domains), your fully qualified tenant name is in the URL `your-tenant.onmicrosoft.com`.

OIDC Well known configuration URL example: 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/spottedmahnb2c.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_SO-Herbener

That said, [OAuth 2](https://oauth.net/2/) and SAML so any library that supports that those technologies support B2C .  For example, [here's a SPA sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-hellojs-singlepageapp) that uses Hello.JS.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just instruct them that you use OpenId Connect or OAuth and point them to your metadata URL? Let them then decide on the library they would like to use.

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes in this case we might have to give the metadata url thats exposed by azure ad b2c, and it will have the domain name "login.microsoftonline.com", by which developers will come to know that we are using azure/microsoft backend. Is there a way to prevent this as well?

Comment: You could use **<tenantName>.b2clogin.com** see B2C [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin) but that also points to what service your using.